# set position of relativelayout

Tags: android

For some reason the position ( margin ) of the layout i have created is not set. the layout shows up at x=0 and y=0. What am I doing wrong?

```
smallPopup = new LinearLayout(this);

LinearLayout.LayoutParams p = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
p.setMargins(100, 100, 10, 10);

smallPopup.setLayoutParams(p);
smallPopup.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
smallPopup.setHorizontalGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
smallPopup.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.map_small_popup_overlay);
smallPopup.setPadding(20, 10, 20, 10);

map.addView(smallPopup, p);
```

Comment: Can you show the creation of 'map' ?

Comment: well, map is just my MapView ( com.google.android.maps.MapView ). If i add the view to android.R.id.content or some other layout with an id, the new layout is still in the left corner.

Comment: thanks, I made a relativelayout container around the mapview and change the code from linearlayout to relativelayout. It works now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several types of LayoutParams, depending on the container of your view.

If you want to position an element inside a MapView you need to use MapView.LayoutParams, which does not support margin (because it does not extend MargingLayoutParams).

MapView.LayoutParams extends AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams, which means you can directly set the x and y values:

```
    WebView.LayoutParams p = new WebView.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 100, 100);
```